# Ionic: Avoid scroll on input focus

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic has this neat feature of scrolling the focussed `<input>` element to the top on focus.

I do not want this behaviour, but instead want the "page" to remain static on `<input>` focus and blur, just letting the keyboard slide in and out.

I there any way I can achieve this without tricking the css?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml add below line to activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Like this

```
 <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

Comment: I am building a pure webapp

Comment: You did not mention that :)